# Using PBC library on Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, library, c

I want to know if there is a way to install/use the [PBC library](http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/) on Arduino UNO. I want to implement some cryptographic primitives using PBC library.

Thank you.

Comment: GMP could be very painful to get working on something as small as the ATmega328P.

Comment: Anyway, I want to know how to do it

Comment: Hello Miss Jéssica Carneiro, Could you tell me "Is it possible to install PBC library on Arduino ?"

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [RELIC](https://github.com/relic-toolkit/) toolkit. It has PCB and they have scripts to compile for Due and Mega. I'm not sure if you could use this with Uno. But this library targets resource-constrained devices.